# How to set a value from a column to another value from another column using Python

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am currently working on a simple project where I am trying to have two sets of column each containing a certain amount of integer numbers. Ex. A column - [ 1, 2, 3, 4] and B column - [.1,.2,.3,.4]. What I am trying to accomplish is,

- Convert all the integer from column A to string ex. [str(num)]
- Set each of the converted strings to values from column B. So example would be string(1) from column A would have the value .1 from column B.

Initially I was trying to following code - but if someone could give me some advice - it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import csv

csv_file = 'Bruv.csv'

names = []
description = []
price = []

with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        names.append(row.get('sizes'))
        description.append(row.get('Product'))
        price.append(row.get('Price'))

print(names)

print(description)

print(price)
```

Comment: Please post code as `formatted text`, not images

Comment: A string in Python can't be assigned a separate value. Do you mean put them in a dictionary or hash table? table = {"1": 0.1, "2": 0.2}. You can retrieve the values by calling table["1"]?

Comment: thank you for your response. I could do a dictionary but that would defeat the purpose. I would like to achieve a way where the code can traverse through an 2 arrays. Then I would like to set 1 of the array values to another. Kind of like A[0] = B[0]. I was thinking of changing one of the arrays to a string array and assign integer values from another array to each of the string value, if that's possible at all. ex. A = [1, 2] & B = [3, 4]. I want to convert A to array of string, A['1', '2'] and then set '1' = 3 and '2' = 4 by traversing through both arrays, if there's such possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're driving at here as simply replacing column A with column B as string seems odd. But since that seems to be what you want:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4] 
 b = [.1,.2,.3,.4]
 df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.array([a,b]).T, columns = ['A', 'B'])
 df['A'] = df['B']
 df['A'] = df['A'].astype('str')

 print(df.dtypes)
 print(df)
```

Out:

```
A     object
B    float64
dtype: object
     A    B
0  0.1 0.10
1  0.2 0.20
2  0.3 0.30
3  0.4 0.40
```

Comment: I want to assign each integer a string as if it were a variable. Like when column A's content become strings - I want to treat them as variables and assign column B's integer values to each of them. I am new to programming. Please correct me if my thought process is wrong!

Comment: if it does the job. since you're reading in a csv, I would recommend using pandas read_csv() to get the data into a data frame.